# How to remove the delimiters from a csv file in ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

I am reading a file which is either separated by a "tab space" or "semicolon(;)" or "comma(,)" below code separates only tab space but i want all 3 to be checked. like if a file is comma separated it should work for that also . Please help!

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'csv'

test = CSV.read('test.csv', headers:true, :col_sep => "\t") 
x = test.headers
puts x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `:col_sep` cannot be a Regexp, which could have solved your problem.

One possible solution would be to analyze the head of your CSV file and count the occurences of possible separators :

```
require 'csv'

possible_separators = ["\t", ';', ',']
lines_to_analyze = 1

File.open('test.csv') do |csv|
  head = csv.first(lines_to_analyze).join
  @col_sep = possible_separators.max_by { |sep| head.count(sep) }
end

@col_sep
#=> ";"
```

You can then use :

```
test = CSV.read('test.csv', headers:true, :col_sep => @col_sep) 
x = test.headers
puts x
# a
# b
# c
```

The values in `x` won't contain any separator.

Comment: but i need the tab spaces/semicolon/comma  removed from the headers coz i need that header names to create a table . how to do it ? @Eric Duminil